# Cannot Recognize ISO in Fedora Core 1 (Yarrow) in VMWare View Player

Tags: fedora, mount, data-cd

It's a long story of why I am trying to do this (basically supporting a business that has not updated their servers in a LONG time). In any case, I am trying to mount an ISO in VMWare View player so I can get access to it inside a snapshot of Yarrow. (I am using VMWare View Player 5.)

When I "Connect" to the ISO, it does see the drive - it even recognizes the name of the image (FC-1 i386). However, when I try to navigate to /mnt/cdrom and perform 'ls', nothing is listed. The application installer keeps asking me for the CD.

Here is my /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/cdrom  /mnt/cdrom  udf,iso9660  noauto,owner,ro  0 0
```

There was a "kudzu" option in with the noauto,owner,ro, but I removed that after doing some reading.

Unfortunately, nothing seems to be working at this point. I know the ROM is good because I used it to install another image of Fedora Core 1 just to test that out. Anybody have any suggestions/pointers?

Comment: I'm guessing that the kernel used in FC1 didn't have support for whatever CDROM device VMware is emulating. (When you say "it sees the drive", you mean that _VMware_ sees it, not the guest OS, right?) Does VMware offer alternate emulations for the CD device? (Maybe a SCSI cdrom drive?) Failing that, try a network install.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at VMware's website (what a novel idea...) they state support for Fedora 11 and above. It is very, very unlikely that it will run. You could try qemu (I've had success with much older Linux versions, up to MCC interim 0.99.10+; but Red Hat 6.2 has problems with X).

Comment: You misunderstood my question. Fedora Core 1 runs great in VMWare View Player. It's just that, when I go to install VMWare Tools, it has some problems reading the CD. I was wondering why it wouldn't correctly mount the CD.